# I have two Queueable Jobs running in a transaction how to resolve it

Tags: apex, future, queue, queueable-apex

On Order Product object I have an integration with a 3rd party system, which sends data the 3rd party whenever the Order Product through Queueable class.

Now I am trying to insert a set of records to another object when a particular field in Order product is updated to a certain value using batch apex using the below class.

```
global class CreateScheduleRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    //List<OrderItem> orderProductList = new List<OrderItem>();
    Map<Id, OrderItem> IdOrderItemMapBatch = new Map<Id, OrderItem>();
    List<Schedule__c> scheduleRecordList = new List<Schedule__c>();

    global CreateScheduleRecords(Map<Id, OrderItem> IdOrderItemMap) {
        IdOrderItemMapBatch = IdOrderItemMap;
        System.debug('Akshay is checking the schedule batch ' + IdOrderItemMapBatch);
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Order.Id, UnitPrice, Quantity, Pacing__c, OL_Left_To_Deliver__c, Line_Item_Start_Date__c, Line_Item_End_Date__c FROM OrderItem WHERE Id in :IdOrderItemMapBatch.keySet()]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<OrderItem> orderProductList) {
        Decimal deliveryQuantity;
        Decimal toBeUpdatedQuantity;
        Integer DeliveryQuantityRemainder;
        String ScheduleDetailsFuture;

        System.debug('Akshay 2 is checking the Queried records ' + orderProductList);
        try {
            for(OrderItem oli : orderProductList) {

                Date a = oli.Line_Item_Start_Date__c;
                Date b = oli.Line_Item_End_Date__c;
                Integer monthDiff = a.monthsBetween(b);
                if (b.day() > a.day()) monthDiff++;
                System.debug('Akshay 3 is checking the differnce in the months ' + monthDiff);

                if(oli.Pacing__c == 'Even') {
                    deliveryQuantity = oli.OL_Left_To_Deliver__c / monthDiff;
                    DeliveryQuantityRemainder = math.mod(Integer.valueOf(oli.OL_Left_To_Deliver__c), monthDiff);
                } else if(oli.Pacing__c == 'Front Load') {
                    deliveryQuantity = oli.OL_Left_To_Deliver__c;
                }

                for(Integer i=0; i<monthDiff; i++) {
                    if(oli.Pacing__c == 'Even') {
                        if(DeliveryQuantityRemainder == 0) {
                            toBeUpdatedQuantity = deliveryQuantity;
                        } else {
                            if(i != 1) {
                                toBeUpdatedQuantity = Math.floor(deliveryQuantity);
                            } else {
                                toBeUpdatedQuantity = Math.floor(deliveryQuantity) + DeliveryQuantityRemainder;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(oli.Pacing__c == 'Front Load') {
                        if(i == 0) {
                            toBeUpdatedQuantity = deliveryQuantity;
                        } else {
                            toBeUpdatedQuantity = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    Schedule__c sc = new Schedule__c();
                    sc.Delivery_Date__c = System.Date.today().toStartOfMonth();
                    sc.Schedule_Status__c = 'Live';
                    sc.Schedule_Type__c = 'Monthly Forecast';
                    sc.Order_Product__c = oli.Id;
                    sc.Order__c = oli.Order.Id;
                    sc.Unit_Price__c = oli.UnitPrice;
                    sc.Quantity__c = toBeUpdatedQuantity;
                    scheduleRecordList.add(sc);
                }

                System.debug('Akshay 4 is checking the Schedule record list ' + scheduleRecordList);

                if(scheduleRecordList != null && !scheduleRecordList.isempty()) {
                        System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable(scheduleRecordList));
                    }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('an error occured while updating the lineitem records ' + e.getMessage() + ' line number ' + e.getLineNumber());
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }


    public class MyQueueable implements Queueable {

        List<Schedule__c> records;
    
        public MyQueueable(List<Schedule__c> records) {
            this.records = records;
        }
    
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
            insert records;
        }
    }

}
```

Now when I try to update this field, two separate queueable jobs are running at the same time which in turn is creating the error **"Too many queueable jobs added to the queue: 2"**
One is the callout that is happening to update the third party and the second is the one that I am running to create a batch of records in another object using the order Item field update.

I tried to use the @future method hoping that it could resolve that, but it didn't work as again it is a queueable method, too.

Can someone please let me know how this can be resolved. Let me know if you need more details on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not move the enqueuing out of the order item loop and have the queueable iterate for sending the details as needed? If not, can you set the batch scope size to 1 so there is only one item passed to execute at a time? BTW if you are calling this batch from a trigger, consider reading [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) and using [this approach](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout).

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for the reply. I did move the enqueuing out of the for loop, but I am still facing the same issue. This is mainly happening because of the future method that is being called by another trigger for a API callout as I mentioned in the question. Can you please tell me if this can be tackled in anyway?

Comment: Read that article and consider the approach it covers (and the example code I provided a link to). Using a future from a trigger, while being recommended by Salesforce, is a broken pattern as the article explains.

Comment: N.B. `scheduleRecordList != null` is superfluous as you initialize it to an empty list